# How to check to see if a table exists in Azure.Data.Tables (v 12.5.0)

Tags: .net, azure, cloud

My data-reading code (currently using Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table) calls a simple method to check to see if a table exists or not; it then make decisions based on that.  (I don't want to create the table if it doesn't exist; I'm just reading here.)

How to do the same thing in Azure.Data.Tables, to which we are now urged to migrate?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As suggested by [christothes](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/28392):

- You can use [`TableServiceClient.Query`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/tables/Azure.Data.Tables/samples/Sample3QueryTables.md#query-tables-1) method.

> a simple method to check to see if a table exists or not; it then make decisions based on that. (I don't want to create the table if it doesn't exist; I'm just reading here.)

```
bool exists = false;
await foreach(var tbl in service.QueryAsync(t => t.Name == "mytable"))
{
   exists = true;
}
```

References: [Migration guide from Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table to Azure.Data.Tables](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/tables/Azure.Data.Tables/MigrationGuide.md) and [Tables migration guide should provide more context on the omission of the Exists method](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/28396)